# fullcalendar confusion with UTC and local date

Tags: javascript, timezone, fullcalendar, momentjs, datetime-conversion

I do let fullcalendar initialize normally. So it represents current date. (Midnight->midnight, 1day, 1h slots)

From some other datasource I get data with timestamps. The format is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" (transmitted as a string, no timezone information)

So I convert that string to a moment object and test against fullcalendar.start and .end to see if it is within.

```
moment("2016-04-07 00:00") == $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end
```

This results in **false** though the following command

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
```

returns

```
"2016-04-07 00:00"
```

I also tried to compare with diff

```
moment("2016-04-07 00:00").diff( $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end,"minutes")
```

which returns

```
120
```

Some research on the calendars.end object in Chrome Dev Tools revealed that it internally is represented as

```
2016-04-07 02:00 GMT+0200
```

This looks strange to me. I am in timezone 2h ahead of GMT. So it should correctly say 2016-04-07 00:00 GMT+0200, should it not?
This also explains why the diff test above resulted in 120 minutes.

Can someone help? I do not get where the conversion problem comes from. I am using only dates with no timezone information. And as said above, fullcalendar initalizes with no gotodate information and shows a time bar from 00:00 to 00:00. So why does it come that there is this 2h difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- The [timezone](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/) parameter controls how FullCalendar works with time zones.
- By default, FullCalendar uses "ambiguously-zoned moments".  These are customizations to moment.js made within fullCalendar.  [The docs state](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/#ambiguously-zoned):

  > The moment object has also been extended to represent a date with no specified timezone. Under the hood, these moments are represented in UTC-mode.

  Thus, to compare dates in this mode, treat them as if they were in UTC.

  ```
  moment.utc("2016-04-07 00:00")
  ```
- To compare moments, use the [moment query functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/), `isSame`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isSameOrBefore`, `isSameOrAfter`, and `isBetween`.
- In this case, since FullCalendar's start is inclusive but the end date is *exclusive*, you probably want to compare like this:

  ```
  var cal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
  var start = cal.start;
  var end = cal.end;

  var m = moment.utc("2016-04-07 00:00");  // your input
  var between = m.isSameOrAfter(start) && m.isBefore(end);
  ```

Note that there's an pending enhancement to moment's `isBetween` functionality for a future release that will give you control of exclusivity, but currently `isBetween` is fully inclusive, so you have to use the combination of functions shown here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot. I do understand things a lot better now.
Some of the dates I tried to compare were 'now'. I got 'now' by

```
var n = moment()
```

That turned out to be a date time including my timezone.

E.g. moment().format() resulted in '2016-04-07 00:00 GMT+0200' and I now see how this went wrong excepting a comparison against full calendar.end to be **true** but it was **false** as '2016-04-07 00:00 GMT+0200' is '2016-04-06 22:00' at UTC.

As

```
moment.utc()
```

does not work, I know ended up with using

```
moment.utc(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
```

This now seems to work as this treats my local time as it would be the 'numerical same time' at UTC.. thus matching with how fullcalendar handles  times internally (ambiguously-zones moments).

Thanks

Comment: Use `moment.utc().startOf('day')`

Comment: unfortunately I have to carry the time portion of the date. So startOf('day') will not work in my case. 
I actually need ambigiously-timezoned "now"